# discovery to health to population to society

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Revisiting academic health sciences systems a decade later: **discovery to health to population to society**
> Until recently, the mission of academic medicine has focused on providing care for complex medical problems, conducting research from discovery to translation, and educating the next generation of scientists and clinicians.
> Source: [The Lancet](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(21)01752-9/fulltext)

Does "discovery to health to population to society" mean "discovery (that is important) to health, (and is important) to population (and is imprtant) to society?

Comment: The highlight text is just a (syntactically highly questionable) list of "sub-sections" within "academic health sciences systems". But in practice they're actually arranged in a meaningful ***sequence***, so we could reasonably think of them as 4 consecutive ***phases*** within a "program" of "health sciences initiatives". That's to say it's presented as a ***process***, within which you do "discovery" first, ***then*** investigate the "health" implications of whatever you found, ***then*** start treating people in the "population", ***then finally*** assess the implications for "society".

Comment: Thank you. Please make your comment as the answer of this thread, because it has the quality of an answer.